# Is it possible to share Nintendo accounts with multiple Switches playing different games simultaneously?

Tags: nintendo-switch, nintendo-account

Tried to Google this question but couldn't find anyone describing the scenario I'm interested in:
Suppose I have a Switch A that is registered as the primary Switch which in this scenario will not play any games. Additionally, I have 2 other Switches (Switch B and Switch C) that would like to play different games simultaneously (Switch B plays game A; Switch C plays game B). Is this possible or can only one secondary Switch play one game? Both Switches will be connected to the internet in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/NintendoSwitch/wiki/gamesharing/):

> You can have the account on three Switches, but you will have one Primary and two secondary Switches (Switch B and Switch C). If Switch B is playing a digital game bought in the in Account 1's profile, you can't play a digital game bought in Account 1's profile on Switch C or one of you will get kicked off.

So you should be able to play different games simultaneously, but only if at least one is a physical copy. Games can't be both digital.

And, as you correctly said, every secondary Switch need to be connected to the internet in order to play game from the main account, as it will check periodically for account activity.